# Setting a variable equal to itself as a string in PHP

Tags: php, variables

hi i want to know how i can make a variable equal to itself.
so if i `echo $var` it show show `$var` on my screen.
ive been trying to write a whole php script to a new file using php, but when i write to the file everything works except my variables disappear and i suspect that its because they equal nothing so im trying to get them to equal themselves.

```
$my_file = '../../../'.$_POST['username'].'.php';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$data = "
<?php


$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'root';
$db_pass        = '';
$db_database    = 'fitnesstest';

$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to establish 
a DB connection');

mysql_select_db($db_database,$con);

$date = strtotime('+3 day');
$dates = date('M d, Y', $date);

mysql_query('INSERT INTO ".$_POST['username']." 
(`id`, `name`, `push_ups`, `sit_ups`,  `burpees`, `pull_ups`, `body_rows`, `overs`,
`tricep_dips`, `run`, `plank_hold`, `squat_hold`, `thrusters`, `hanging_abs`, `row`,
`weight`, `bi`, `tri`, `s_scap`, `s_illiac`, `arm`, `chest_hip`, `waist`,
`belly_delts`, `thigh`) 
VALUES 
(NULL, '$dates', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 
'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0')');

?>

";
 file_put_contents($my_file, $data);
 fclose($handle);
```

every variable in `$data` becomes a blank space in the new file that its written to.
please help, it will be much appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrap it in single quotes, not double quotes

Comment: i'll give it a try but im pretty sure thats how it was when i first tried

Comment: @user2707380 in single quoted strings, PHP variables will not be evaluated as they are in double quoted strings. Read the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because variables expand inside of double quotes. Check the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) on this.

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Use single quotes (`'`) to enclose it or escape all special characters (such as turn `$` into `\$`) to avoid this.

More reading [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Another thing you could do in this unique case is create a `template.tpl` with your contents, but instead of `mysql_query('INSERT INTO ".$_POST['username']."` you could have `mysql_query('INSERT INTO %%USERNAME%%` and simply replace `%%USERNAME%%` and `%%DATES%%` when reading the template file. The added bonus to this is the fact that you get full syntax highlighting (since it's not in a string).

---

Create a file called `sql.php.tpl` with the following contents:

```
<?php
    $db_host        = 'localhost';
    $db_user        = 'root';
    $db_pass        = '';
    $db_database    = 'fitnesstest';

    $con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to establish 
    a DB connection');

    mysql_select_db($db_database,$con);

    $date = strtotime('+3 day');
    $dates = date('M d, Y', $date);

    mysql_query('INSERT INTO %%USERNAME%%
    (`id`, `name`, `push_ups`, `sit_ups`,  `burpees`, `pull_ups`, `body_rows`, `overs`,
    `tricep_dips`, `run`, `plank_hold`, `squat_hold`, `thrusters`, `hanging_abs`, `row`,
    `weight`, `bi`, `tri`, `s_scap`, `s_illiac`, `arm`, `chest_hip`, `waist`,
    `belly_delts`, `thigh`) 
    VALUES 
    (NULL, '" . mysql_real_escape_string($dates) . "', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 
    '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0')');
?>
```

and then read it:

```
<?php
    $template = file_get_contents("sql.php.tpl");
    $template = str_replace("%%USERNAME%%", $_POST["username"], $template);
    file_put_contents("user.php", $template);
?>
```

**Disclamer:** What you're doing is a VERY bad idea. You've got SQL injections left and right. You're creating new files on the operative system (I could simply have a username called `'); shell_exec("rm -rf /");` and destroy your entire server. You're having tables for each user.

Comment: i'll give that a try, The $_POST['username'] works like it should. are you saying i should replace the double quotes with single in the variable $data?

Comment: @user2707380 Yes, but then you need to replace `'` with `\'` everywhere. Use a template file to avoid this.

Comment: i know this is probably asking a bit much but could you please rewrite my code the way you think it should be, because in trying 100 different things and now in getting errors on my page that i never had before

Comment: @camz17 Check out my update, but PLEASE do not copy paste the code - it is full of flaws and bad logic. Use it as an example what you *could* do. People can **destroy** your server if you use this code.

Comment: users cant sign up by themselves, only i can sign them up

Comment: @camz17 But why are you creating an entirely new PHP file and not just executing it right there and then?

Comment: its for a cron job that has to execute every 39 days

Comment: Couldn't you just (in that cronjob) loop through all your users and then run this code?

Comment: it has to run only for certain users sometimes even one user, i figured this was the easiest way, as soon as i sign someone up it creates a cron job and a separate file for that cron job to execute 39 days after they sign up

Comment: @camz17 I'd suggest that you in your `users` table (**one single table**) create a `next_check` DATETIME field, and then `SELECT` all users where `next_check < NOW()` in your `users` table.

Comment: one more question, do i need those single qoutes around all the 0's? coz if not then i think i've solved my problem

Comment: ive dot one table for my users, but then i've got another one just for this job, im stressed for time, and i know security wont be an issue, maybe when i get the chance i'll fix it but this will have to do for now

Comment: @camz No you don't - not if it's a number in MySQL. Any string will fail if you don't use quotes though.

Answer (score 2):

Best would be to use [Nowdoc Syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) if you are working with PHP 5.3+ (which you should). That way you don't run into escaping problems with single or double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use **HEREDOC** I guess. Safe bet is **NOWDOC**

```
<?php
$my_file = '../../../'.$_POST['username'].'.php';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$data=<<<'CODE'
<?php


$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'root';
$db_pass        = '';
$db_database    = 'fitnesstest';

$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to establish
a DB connection');

mysql_select_db($db_database,$con);

$date = strtotime('+3 day');
$dates = date('M d, Y', $date);

mysql_query('INSERT INTO ".$_POST['username']."
(`id`, `name`, `push_ups`, `sit_ups`,  `burpees`, `pull_ups`, `body_rows`, `overs`,
`tricep_dips`, `run`, `plank_hold`, `squat_hold`, `thrusters`, `hanging_abs`, `row`,
`weight`, `bi`, `tri`, `s_scap`, `s_illiac`, `arm`, `chest_hip`, `waist`,
`belly_delts`, `thigh`)
VALUES
(NULL, '$dates', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0')');

?>

CODE;
file_put_contents($my_file, $data);
fclose($handle);
```